# FFMpeg encoding using AAC gives 1509 bitrate

Tags: ffmpeg, aac

FFMpeg using the native AAC codec is always creating files with a 1509 kb/s bitrate.

If I use the switch -c:a aac the FFMpeg readout says it is encoding at the default 128, but when I analyse the created file with several utilities it says 1509 kb/s.

If I use -c:a aac -b:a 256k, again FFMpeg says its encoding at 256, but the resulting file is also 1509.

Where am I going wrong please, I expect I'm missing something...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out FFMpeg is working corrently, Mediainfo and Windows were incorrectly reporting the bitrate of the file. If I extract the audio and then measure the bitrate again I get the correct answer.

Also if I remux the .MKV files I also then get the correct bitrate reported.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).